# boost_1_60_0 .zip installation in windows

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I have performed below steps for windows 7

```
Boost link http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/

1. Downloaded boost_1_60_0 .zip

2. cd \boost_1_60_0\tools\build

3. Ran below command in command prompt

bootstrap.bat gcc        
bjam --toolset=gcc "--prefix=C:\DestinationFolder" install


Now i have b2.exe & bjam.exe in C:\DestinationFolder\bin
```

Can anyone please help me in what to do next as I am unable to process further

Comment: Which compiler do you have? Are you really sure that it is gcc?

Comment: I have MinGW  installed

Comment: And i took reference from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947542/building-boost-on-windows

Comment: I even tried to understand/follow steps at
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

Comment: I would rather use the [prebuilt Windows binaries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.60.0/).

Comment: @RHertel Thanks ... i will try this

Comment: @RHertel can you please direct me to steps for using prebuilt windows binaries

Comment: I have done this a while ago, so I don't remember every step; but I think it was fairly easy: Download the latest version, `boost_1_60_0-msvc-14.0-64.exe` or `boost_1_60_0-msvc-14.0-32.exe` (64 or 32 bit, depending on your system), and run the exe file (e.g., open in a folder and double-click). This should start an interactive installer which, as I recall, of the usual type. Sorry that I can't be more specific. The only part I found somewhat more difficult was to ensure that the compiler finds the libraries. I think I needed to add the installation directory to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Yes i figured that our looking at .exe file. Thanks a lot.. this is the first time I am working on C++ so I got bit confused.

Answer (score 12):

Since yours is now the third "How do I build boost on Windows?" question that I've seen since `1.60.0` was released here are my own personal Windows boost build notes:

Windows does not directly support boost, so you can download it and put it wherever you want.
The boost user guide recommends creating a `BOOST_ROOT` environment variable with the location of boost.

Note: in the following examples `2>&1 | tee ??_build.txt` is optional, but it's useful to keep a build log...

## Building for Visual Studio 2015

In a Visual Studio tools Command Prompt:

```
cd boost_1_xx_0
call bootstrap.bat
```

For static libraries:

```
b2 -j8 toolset=msvc-14.0 address-model=64 architecture=x86 link=static threading=multi runtime-link=shared --build-type=complete stage
2>&1 | tee msvc_static_build.txt
```

Note: thread must be built with dynamic linking see: https://studiofreya.com/2015/05/20/the-simplest-way-of-building-boost-1-58-for-32-bit-and-64-bit-architectures-with-visual-studio/

For dynamic thread library:

```
b2 -j8 toolset=msvc-14.0 address-model=64 architecture=x86 link=shared threading=multi runtime-link=shared --with-thread --build-type=minimal stage
2>&1 | tee msvc_thread_build.txt
```

For all as dynamic libraries:

```
b2 -j8 toolset=msvc-14.0 address-model=64 architecture=x86 link=shared threading=multi runtime-link=shared --build-type=complete stage
2>&1 | tee msvc_dynamic_build.txt
```

## Building for MinGw

Ensure that gcc/mingw is in the path, e.g.: C:\Qt\Tools\mingw491_32\bin

```
cd boost_1_xx_0
bootstrap.bat mingw

b2 toolset=gcc link=shared threading=multi --build-type=complete stage
2>&1 | tee mingw_build.txt
```

Note: since `boost 1.61.0` you may need to change: `bootstrap.bat mingw` to `bootstrap.bat gcc`

Comment: I created a gist for it https://gist.github.com/sim642/29caef3cc8afaa273ce6. hope it helps