# Unable to link to boost 1.60 thread library in Visual Studio 2013 on Window 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

i am trying to use boost 1.60 thread library in my project with visual studio 2013 on window 7. Following command i used to build boost

```
b2.exe toolset=msvc-12.0 variant=debug link=shared threading=multi address-model=32 -j5 --build-dir=some_directory --libdir=some_directory install
```

Though building was successful when i add thread library in visual studio linker input option i get error saying

```
error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_60.lib'
```

**Few NOTES::**
1. Is boost directory is in include path : **Yes**
2. Is boost lib directory is added to additional lib directory path : **Yes**
3. Is boost lib dll is in application's environment path : **Yes**
4. Did i build boost with different version of visual studio and trying to use in different version : **No, both is VS2013**
5. Is boost build address model is different than application's address model : **No, both is 32 bit**

after checking multiple times all of the above my knowledge base ends on this :(
 kindly extend it solve this problem. What else i need to check?

Comment: have a look at my previous answer here: [boost-1-60-0-zip-installation-in-windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217511/boost-1-60-0-zip-installation-in-windows/35223257#35223257) Note: thread **must** be dynamically linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who gets into same problem in future..
Just make sure you have added preprocessor flag **BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK** if you are using shared library version of Boost