# Qn regarding boost for vs 2013

Tags: c++, boost

In the thread here [How to use Boost in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629421/how-to-use-boost-in-visual-studio-2010) he teach how to set up boost for visual studio 2010.

If you want to use the part of boost that require building, but none of the features that requires external dependencies, then building it is fairly simple.

1. Unarchive the latest version of boost (1.47.0 as of writing) into a directory of your choice (e.g. C:\boost_1_47_0).
2. Start the Visual Studio Command Prompt for the platform of your choice and navigate to where boost is.
3. Run: bootstrap.bat to build b2.exe (previously named bjam).
4. Run: bootstrap.bat to build b2.exe (previously named bjam).

   Run b2:

   Win32: b2 --toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete stage ; x64:

b2 --toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete architecture=x86 address-model=64 stage

What if I is using visual studio 2013 ? Do i change mscv-10.0 to mscv-13.0 ? because mscv = microsoft visual studio is it correct ?

He also say this
Edit the Library Directories section to include the path to your boost libraries output. (The default for the example and instructions above would be C:\boost_1_47_0\stage\lib. Rename and move the directory first if you want to have x86 & x64 side by side (such as to \lib\x86 & \lib\x64).

What he mean ? I run b2 twice then do what ? I run b2 for win32 then keep it in separate directory then run b2 for x64 ? Or i run win32 and x64 then keep result in one directory then run it again and keep result in another directory ? Means run 4 times ? Some help please. I dunno how to set up boost. Please respond if not i have to create another thraed

Comment: You could skip all of this and just download the [Windows Binaries here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.61.0/).

Comment: See [building boost for windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217511/boost-1-60-0-zip-installation-in-windows/35223257#35223257) if I remember correctly I think you need `--toolset=msvc-12.0` for `visual studio 2013`. Yes, you will need to build it twice into separate locations if you want both 32 bit and 64 bit libraries and then edit the `Library Directories` for 64 and 32 bit builds accordingly.

Comment: Would i be able to use boost.python if I install the exe file ?

Comment: @cschua All of the boost libraries that require building for Visual Studio are available at the link I posted.  In other words, someone already did the hard work for you, and it's right there at the link.

Comment: But what difference does it make if i run the 2 commands twice only to keep them in separate directories ? do i have to edit the commands or something

Comment: Thank you paul. I will download it and try it out

Comment: I guess the Visual Studio boost advocates found it advantageous to have the libraries already built, so that adoption of boost becomes simple rather than a pain.