# Visual Studio 2015 update 2 can't link boost libs, got LNK2019, LNK2001, etc

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, boost

I want make a facial recognition test. Have compiled **boost1.61.0**, and added to the include, libs of the vs.

But I got some errors when I try to run my project.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you've built the `boost` libraries correctly see: [building boost for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217511/boost-1-60-0-zip-installation-in-windows/35223257#35223257), you also need to add `stage/$(Platform)/lib` as additional library directory in the project settings.

Ideally you should set `stage/$(Platform)/lib` for all configuration types and for all platforms, see: [building boost for visual studio 2013](https://studiofreya.com/2015/05/20/building-boost-1-58-for-32-bit-and-64-bit-architectures-with-visual-studio-2013/)

Note, `boost` enables autolinking with `Visual Studio` by default, unless you define the macro `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB`

Comment: Or install the libraries somewhere, rather than using them from the temporary staging directory.

Comment: Thank you, I will make sure that later.