# Running Boost bootstrap

Tags: c++, boost, build

I need to build Boost libraries. When I run bootstrap.bat, I get the following:

`Building Boost.Build engine
\GnuWin32\bin"" was unexpected at this time.`

Can anyone explain what's going on? Thanks.

**Update**: I've tried this both in vanilla command prompt and VS2015 developer/Msbuild command prompt. Doesn't make a difference.

My environment: Windows 10 1607 (build 14393.693), MS VS 2015.

PS. This is happening with both Boost 1.58 and 1.63.

Comment: may be help [boost on window](https://andres.jaimes.net/718/how-to-install-the-c-boost-libraries-on-windows/)

Comment: I just ran bootstrap.bat without any other options, as recommended in several places. Before, this used to work.

Comment: Take a look at [boost_1_60_0 .zip installation in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217511/boost-1-60-0-zip-installation-in-windows/35223257#35223257) and note: *In a Visual Studio tools Command Prompt* and/or *Ensure that gcc/mingw is in the path*...

Comment: Why the negative votes? I tried this both in VS command prompt and in vanilla (admin) command prompt. Doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright, I had double quotes around my GnuWin path in my PATH variable. Removing them solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried `boostrap msvc` and works.

Only providing `boostrap` doesn't work, even if I use `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017`.

Check the `bootstrap.log` file if you failed.