# error trying to boost build mingw

Tags: gcc, boost, mingw

This is my first time trying to use boost.  I really don't know what I am doing.  If I've forgot something basic please forgive me.  Thanks for any help.  Getting the following error when trying to build connection using boost.  I have installed mingw.  I get the following response when trying to run a command.  What have I missed?

```
C:\boost_1_63_0\tools\build\src\engine>build.bat mingw
###
### Using 'mingw' toolset.
###

C:\boost_1_63_0\tools\build\src\engine>if exist bootstrap rd /S /Q bootstrap

C:\boost_1_63_0\tools\build\src\engine>md bootstrap

C:\boost_1_63_0\tools\build\src\engine>gcc -DNT -o bootstrap\jam0.exe  command.c compile.c constants.c debug.c execcmd.c execnt.c filent.c frames.c function.c glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c object.c option.c output.c parse.c pathnt.c pathsys.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c md5.c class.c cwd.c w32_getreg.c native.c modules/set.c modules/path.c modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c modules/order.c
execcmd.c: In function 'onintr':
execcmd.c:120:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'out_printf' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     out_printf( "...interrupted\n" );
     ^
execnt.c: In function 'maxline':
execnt.c:524:12: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'result' [-Wimplicit-int]
     static result;
            ^
filent.c: In function 'file_archscan':
filent.c:358:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'filelist_empty' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     if ( filelist_empty( archive->members ) )
          ^
filent.c:360:14: warning: implicit declaration of function 'file_collect_archive_content_' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         if ( file_collect_archive_content_( archive ) < 0 )
              ^
make.c: In function 'make':
make.c:132:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'out_printf' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             out_printf( "...found %d target%s...\n", counts->targets,
             ^
make.c: In function 'make0':
make.c:735:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'out_flush' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             out_flush();
             ^
filesys.c: In function 'file_archivescan_impl':
filesys.c:360:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'filelist_empty' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     if ( filelist_empty( archive->members ) )
          ^
modules/path.c: In function 'path_exists':
modules/path.c:16:12: warning: implicit declaration of function 'file_query' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     return file_query( list_front( lol_get( frame->args, 0 ) ) ) ?
            ^

C:\boost_1_63_0\tools\build\src\engine>.\bootstrap\jam0 -f build.jam --toolset=mingw "--toolset-root= "  clean
###
### Unknown toolset: mingw
###
### Known toolsets are: acc, borland, cc, como, clang, darwin, gcc, gcc-nocygwin, intel-darwin, intel-linux, intel-win32, kcc, kylix, metrowerks, mipspro, msvc, qcc, pathscale, pgi, sun, sunpro, tru64cxx, vacpp, xlcpp, vc7, vc8, vc9, vc10, vc11, vc12, vc14, vc15, vmsdecc
###

C:\boost_1_63_0\tools\build\src\engine>.\bootstrap\jam0 -f build.jam --toolset=mingw "--toolset-root= "
###
### Unknown toolset: mingw
###
### Known toolsets are: acc, borland, cc, como, clang, darwin, gcc, gcc-nocygwin, intel-darwin, intel-linux, intel-win32, kcc, kylix, metrowerks, mipspro, msvc, qcc, pathscale, pgi, sun, sunpro, tru64cxx, vacpp, xlcpp, vc7, vc8, vc9, vc10, vc11, vc12, vc14, vc15, vmsdecc
###

C:\boost_1_63_0\tools\build\src\engine>exit /b 1
```

Comment: You've missed reading the instructions! Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217511/boost-1-60-0-zip-installation-in-windows/35223257#35223257) or [boost: Getting Started on Windows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/more/getting_started/windows.html)

Comment: same problem here. Have you fixed the problem?