# boost c++ library build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I was trying to build boost but encountering this error (log attached below) although there is nothing as bin.ntx86 exiting. Does anyone have a solution? I was using vs2010 command tool to build.

```
    [MKDIR] bin.ntx86
    A subdirectory or file bin.ntx86 already exists.

    md "bin.ntx86"

   ...failed [MKDIR] bin.ntx86...
   ...skipped b2.exe for lack of bin.ntx86...
   ...skipped bjam.exe for lack of b2.exe...
   ...failed updating 1 target...
   ...skipped 2 targets...
```

Comment: Save yourself all of this trouble and get the [prebuilt boost binaries for Visual Studio](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.64.0/)

Comment: Or read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217511/boost-1-60-0-zip-installation-in-windows/35223257#35223257). Note: I believe that the tool set for `VS2010` is `msvc-10.0`

Comment: Great solution! Thank you so much!