# Building Boost 1.65.0 with minGW 4.9.2

Tags: boost

## Background

Planning to use some tools offered by Boost for file system traversing & picking up relevant file names. (May extend to other capabilities provided by Boost if required).

IDE used : *Codeblocks 16.0.1*
Compiler : *minGW 4.9.2* (Comes with standard installation of the IDE above)
OS          : *Version 10.0.15063*

## What I've done so far

1. Setting minGW to SysPath
2. Download and extract boost_1_65_0 to C:\User\user\Documents\boost_1_65_0
3. Using CMD to invoke the bootstrap with gcc toolset via 
   `bootstrap.bat gcc`
    (*encountered **error-01***)
4. Use the alternative provided by Boost to download prebuild binaries of Boost-Jam.
5. Downloaded and built the Boost-Jam resulting the creation of **bin.ntx86** directory in the directory of Boost Jam (version 3.1.18) via the command 
   `build.bat gcc`
6. Added the directory of ..\boost-jam-3.1.18\bin.ntx86 to SysPath
7. Try to build boost again via the command 
   `bjam --toolset=gcc "--prefix=D:\SoftwareDevelopmentTools\CodeBlocks" install` 
   (*encountered **error-02** & **warning-01***) 
   **Note: Item 7 is based on the instruction given at** [Codeblocks BoostWindowsQuickRef](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/BoostWindowsQuickRef#Build_Boost)

## Errors Encountered

**Error-01 :**

> Building Boost.Build engine
>   C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccayvfUp.o:execnt.c:(.text+0x1237): `undefined reference to UnregisterWait`
>   C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccayvfUp.o:execnt.c:(.text+0x12fe): `undefined reference to RegisterWaitForSingleObject`
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Output on `bootstrap.log`

> ###
>   ### Using 'gcc' toolset.
>   ###
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\boost_1_65_0\tools\build\src\engine>if exist bootstrap rd /S /Q bootstrap 
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\boost_1_65_0\tools\build\src\engine>md bootstrap
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\boost_1_65_0\tools\build\src\engine>gcc -DNT -o bootstrap\jam0.exe  command.c compile.c constants.c debug.c execcmd.c execnt.c filent.c frames.c function.c glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c object.c option.c output.c parse.c pathnt.c pathsys.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c md5.c class.c cwd.c w32_getreg.c native.c modules/set.c modules/path.c modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c modules/order.c 
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\boost_1_65_0\tools\build\src\engine>exit /b 1

**Error-02 :**
Do note that this is on the output after *warning-01 (see below under Warning Encountered)*

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   C:/Users/user/Documents/boost_1_65_0/tools/build/src/tools\python.jam:669: in declare-libpython-target
>   *** argument error
>   * rule split-version ( version )
>   * called with: (  )
>   * missing argument version
>   C:/Users/user/Documents/boost_1_65_0/tools/build/src/tools\python.jam:383:see definition of rule 'split-version' being called
>   C:/Users/user/Documents/boost_1_65_0/tools/build/src/tools\python.jam:971: in configure
>   C:/Users/user/Documents/boost_1_65_0/tools/build/src/tools\python.jam:115: in python.init
>   C:/Users/user/Documents/boost_1_65_0/tools/build/src/build\toolset.jam:42: in using
>   libs\python\build\Jamfile:17: in modules.load
>   C:/Users/user/Documents/boost_1_65_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:325: in load-jamfile
>   C:/Users/user/Documents/boost_1_65_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:64: in load
>   C:/Users/user/Documents/boost_1_65_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:89: in load-used-projects
>   C:/Users/user/Documents/boost_1_65_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:75: in load
>   C:/Users/user/Documents/boost_1_65_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:145: in project.find
>   C:/Users/user/Documents/boost_1_65_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:535: in load
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\boost_1_65_0\tools\build\src/kernel\modules.jam:295: in import
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\boost_1_65_0\tools\build\src\kernel\bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\boost_1_65_0\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope

## Warning Encountered

**Warning-01 :**

> warning: mismatched versions of Boost.Build engine and core
>   warning: Boost.Build engine (bjam) is 03.1.18
>   warning: Boost.Build core (at C:/Users/user/Documents/boost_1_65_0/tools/build/src) is 2015.07-git

I am thoroughly confused as to what I've done wrong or steps I might have missed. This is the 6th time I've ever tried to build boost

## Update 01

Installed Python 3.6 and restart the build with this command
`bjam --toolset=gcc "--prefix=D:\SoftwareDevelopmentTools\CodeBlocks" install`

Encountered this error

> C:/Users/user/Documents/boost_1_65_0/tools/build/src/util\path.jam:458: in **path.makedirs
>   rule MAKEDIR unknown in module path**.
>   C:/Users/user/Documents/boost_1_65_0/tools/build/src/build\configure.jam:279: in configure.set-log-file
>   C:/Users/user/Documents/boost_1_65_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:679: in load
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\boost_1_65_0\tools\build\src/kernel\modules.jam:295: in import
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\boost_1_65_0\tools\build\src\kernel\bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\boost_1_65_0\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope

Comment: Don't worry @NickyHFE your'e not alone. The instructions I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217511/boost-1-60-0-zip-installation-in-windows/35223257#35223257) still work for me. However, Python 3.6 is installed on my machine, which may be the difference...

Comment: Hmmm.. I'll try to install Py to see if the difference is made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SOLVED

Most probable cause : Boost.Build for Boost v1.65.0 is not compilable with GCC 4.9.2.

Changed the toolset gcc with a much more recent GCC v6.3.0 (got via minGW-get)

Answer (score 1):

Try change WINVER to 0x0500 (like on Windows XP). The simplest way - edit strings in file %CodeBlocks%\MinGW\include\windef.h:

```
#ifndef WINVER
#define WINVER 0x0400
```

to

```
#ifndef WINVER
//#define WINVER 0x0400
#define WINVER 0x0500
```

That must solve your problem.

PS: %CodeBlocks% - Dir in that CodeBlocks was installed.