# Program doesn't start when linking boost filesystem

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I'm trying to run a helloworld program which uses boost filesystem.
I'm on Windows with MinGW 8.1 and boost 1.70.
The problem is that, although everything compiles, the program doesn't run. I mean, it runs but doesn't print anything, which means the main function is not even executed:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::string_literals;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello Boost!" << endl;

    fs::path abHome{"C:/Users/Me"s};
    fs::path jsonFile = abHome / "jsonFile.json"s;
    if (!fs::exists(jsonFile)) {
        cout << "Creating json file from scratch." << endl;
    }
}
```

"Hello Boost" isn't ever printed to the console.
I've compiled with both CMake and g++ from command line to try to better understand what's going on:

g++ main.cpp -o main -L"C:/Code/boost_1_70_0/stage/lib" -lboost_filesystem-mgw81-mt-x64-1_70 -lboost_system-mgw81-mt-x64-1_70 -I"C:/Code/boost_1_70_0"

I've compiled boost for MinGW by following the guide and everything went well, in the output folder I see many different versions of each library based on the default targets (I haven't really picked them, just went with the defaults).

How can I debug the launch of main.exe to see what's causing the crash? It's been many years since I wrote C++ so I need help to get back on track! :)

Comment: First, how did you conclude that the issue is with boost?  Did you try a simple hello world program that doesn't use boost?

Comment: That code works for me. Try starting with a simpler "hello world" program, and gradually add Boost.Filesystem parts so you can identify what exactly is causing problems with your setup.

Comment: I concluded that it has something to do with boost because if I comment out the lines of code that use fs the “hello boost” is actually printed out :) even if I leave the import from boost uncommented it works, so it has something to do with the boost code that is in the linked dll, right?

Comment: Have you added `C:/Code/boost_1_70_0/stage/lib` to your `$PATH` so that `Windows` can find `libboost_filesystem-mgw81-mt-x64-1_70.dll`?

Comment: @kenba that was it... can you explain to me why I need that? The build executable for this ridiculously short program is 3.7MB in size and the library I linked is static, so I thought it would be included in the .exe!

Comment: The library that you linked must have been shared, otherwise it would not have needed the `dll` file... It is quite normal to build `boost` as `shared` libraries for `MinGw` as some libraries are required to be `shared`, see [boost installation in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217511/boost-1-60-0-zip-installation-in-windows/35223257#35223257)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, as @kenba pointed out, that the *dynamic* linking of the boost dlls was failing.
I erroneously thought I had linked the static version of the boost libraries.
To actually achieve that I should have used this command:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -L"C:/Code/boost_1_70_0/stage/lib" -l:"libboost_filesystem-mgw81-mt-x64-1_70.a" -l:"libboost_system-mgw81-mt-x64-1_70.a" -I"C:/Code/boost_1_70_0"
```

instead of the one I posted in the OP.