# Building boost 1.75.0 library with mingw - b2 does nothing

Tags: c++, boost, mingw

I'm trying to build boost libraries on windows using mingw compiler. I'm following instructions from [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary) (section 5.2). I've successfully gone through step one and two. I had to change `.\bootstrap.bat` to `.\bootstrap.bat mingw`. The next step, running b2.exe, seems to do nothing. I've tried changing --prefix, --build-dir, toolset.
What may be the problem?

Comment: See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217511/boost-1-60-0-zip-installation-in-windows/35223257#35223257). The key issue is to call `.\bootstrap.bat gcc` before calling `.\b2 toolset=gcc`

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions it's not `b2.exe` but `bjam.exe` (located under `tools/build/src/engine/bjam.exe`).
When I build boost 1.75.0 with MinGW-w64 under the MSYS2 shell the command looks something like:

```
INSTALLPREFIX=/usr/local
BITS=64
$COMSPEC //C "CD tools\\build & bootstrap.bat mingw" &&
BOOST_ROOT=$(pwd) MINGW=/ tools/build/src/engine/bjam.exe -q --prefix=$INSTALLPREFIX --build-dir=build_win --build-type=complete --layout=tagged --enable-icu --disable-filesystem2 toolset=gcc target-os=windows abi=ms link=static,shared runtime-link=static,shared variant=release threading=single,multi threadapi=win32 context-impl=fcontext address-model=$BITS --without-python --without-mpi release stage install cxxflags="-fpermissive -DBOOST_LOG_WITHOUT_SYSLOG"
```