# How do you build boost windows library thread_win32?

Tags: winapi, boost, mingw32, usrp, uhd

I am writing about a problem I am having trying to get a third-party library to build with mingw32-make.exe and a Boost 1.67.0 dependency on Windows 10.

I am setting the variable **Boost_INCLUDE_DIR** to <path_to_boost>\boost_1_67_0\include

I am setting the variable **Boost_LIBRARY_DIR** to <path_to_boost>\boost_1_67_0\lib

and the cmake-gui output comes out with the following error message:

[image: Error Message Describing missing thread_win32 library]

because, I imagine, I do not have the libboost_thread_win32.a library included in my boost installation (shown below).

[image: Libraries included in my boost installation]

How do I resolve this? Is there a way to easily build boost with this thread_win32 library using minGW?

Comment: that actually looks like a CMake Bug. you could try removing the "1.58" version requirement from `find_package("Boost", "1.58")` in UHDBoost.cmake line 176

Comment: that's why I said, "looks like a CMake bug"

Comment: If I modify FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake to ignore the error, then I get an error further down the line...

"Cmake Error at cmake/Modules/UHDComponent.cmake:59 (message):
     Dependencies for required component LibUHD not met.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
     CMakeLists.txt:363 (LIBUHD_REGISTER_COMPONENT)"

So it looks like boost thread_win32 library built with mingw32 might be essential?

Answer (score 0):

To build `boost 1.67.0` on `Windows` for `cmake` you need to set the variables:

- `BOOST_ROOT` to <path_to_boost>\boost_1_67_0
- and `BOOST_LIBRARY_DIR` to the path where you have built `boost`.
  E.g. <path_to_boost>\boost_1_67_0\stage if you follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217511/boost-1-60-0-zip-installation-in-windows/35223257#35223257)